# Is there a way to highlight symlinks in the speedbar?

Tags: speedbar, symbolic-links

I would like files in the speedbar that are symlinks, to be highlighted, or at least marked with @ so that they are easily distinguishable.

Comment: I do something similar in a custom version of `speedbar` that is not presently publicly available.  In my custom version, I modified `speedbar-default-directory-list` and used a `file-symlink-p` test ....  In the stock version of `speedbar`, there is no built-in symlink test  -- thus, a custom solution that modifies one or more aspects of that library would be required to answer this question.  This is not something that can be easily done with `advice` ...

Comment: @lawlist Thanks, as I suspected. So I'll take the plunge and write some more elisp.

Comment: I went ahead and wrote-up a solution, but it requires adding a couple of faces and modifying `speedbar-insert-files-at-point`, which is called by `speedbar-default-directory-list`.  Other than modifying a core function of `speedbar.el`, I see no other easy way to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment underneath the question above, there is no built-in support for identifying a symlink using the `speedbar` library.  The following code adds that support -- differentiating between a symlink directory versus a filename.  Evaluate the code below and then open a speedbar window, or refresh a window if it is already open.

```lisp
(require 'speedbar)

(defface speedbar-symlink-directory-face
  '((((class color) (background light)) :foreground "red")
    (((class color) (background dark)) :foreground "green"))
  "Speedbar face for symlinked directory names."
  :group 'speedbar-faces)

(defface speedbar-symlink-filename-face
  '((((class color) (background light)) :foreground "purple")
    (((class color) (background dark)) :foreground "yellow"))
  "Speedbar face for symlinked filenames."
  :group 'speedbar-faces)

(defun speedbar-insert-files-at-point (files level)
  "Insert list of FILES starting at point, and indenting all files to LEVEL.
Tag expandable items with a +, otherwise a ?.  Don't highlight ? as we
don't know how to manage them.  The input parameter FILES is a cons
cell of the form (DIRLIST . FILELIST)."
  ;; Start inserting all the directories
  (let ((dirs (car files)))
    (while dirs
      (speedbar-make-tag-line 'angle
                              ?+
                              'speedbar-dired
                              (car dirs)
                              (car dirs)
                              'speedbar-dir-follow
                              nil
                              (if (file-symlink-p (car dirs))
                                'speedbar-symlink-directory-face
                                'speedbar-directory-face)
                              level)
      (setq dirs (cdr dirs))))
  (let ((lst (car (cdr files)))
        (case-fold-search t))
    (while lst
      (let* ((known (string-match speedbar-file-regexp (car lst)))
             (expchar (if known ?+ ??))
             (fn (if known 'speedbar-tag-file nil)))
        (when (or speedbar-show-unknown-files (/= expchar ??))
          (speedbar-make-tag-line 'bracket
                                  expchar
                                  fn
                                  (car lst)
                                  (car lst)
                                  'speedbar-find-file
                                  nil
                                  (if (file-symlink-p (car lst))
                                    'speedbar-symlink-filename-face
                                    'speedbar-file-face)
                                  level)))
      (setq lst (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: Mucho Gracias, I will add this to my  well-fatted .emacs file